# Print file contents in decreasing order java

Tags: java

I need to write a Java program where I can read data from a file which has students names and grades. I must find the max grade for each student and then write his name and max grade in a new file. I have been able to do this. The thing is, students should be printed in decreasing order based on their max grade and I can't find out how to do that. Can you help me please? Thank you!

```
public class NotaMax {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws FileNotFoundException{
        Scanner input=new Scanner(new File("teksti.txt"));
        PrintStream output=new PrintStream(new File("max.txt"));
        while(input.hasNextLine()) {
            String rreshti=input.nextLine();
            max(rreshti,output);
        }
    }

    public static void max(String text,PrintStream output) {
        Scanner data=new Scanner(text);
        String emri=data.next();
        double max=0;
        while(data.hasNext()) {
            double nota=data.nextDouble();
            if(nota>max) {
                max=nota;
            }
        }
        output.println(""+emri+":"+max);
    }
}
```

Comment: You can put all the records in ArrayList and later on sort them using Collections interface's sorting methods

Comment: Can you help me with some code if possible cause I'm not familiar with this

Comment: @m_lat I write an answer with some code, if you want extra explanation comment on that answer.

Answer (score 1):

There are two approaches for this, one filling up the other.

You can save them in an `ArrayList` and then call the method `Array#reverse` so it will reverse the `ArrayList`. To add another layer of certainty, it's better to make an `Object`/`Class` named `Student` and apply a `Comparator` to the `#sort` method of the `ArrayList` in order to assure the outcome.
This however takes a lot more steps than the easiest and most efficient way of tackling this problem.

What the best you could do is save the `Student Object` inside an `ArrayList` (or `HashSet`, really any `Comparable Collection/Map`) and use the `#sort` method to sort it from the down to the top.
I could (if requested), provide some code for this.

Comment: Can you help me with some code if possible cause I'm not familiar with this

Comment: I will edit my post with the code, so it'll appear, i'll comment once i've added the code.

Answer (score 1):

First thing that comes to my mind is creating a separate class for your students and implementing a simple binary heap as a maximum heap with max grade of each student as a sorting criteria. Then just printing it. Shouldn't be to hard.

Comment: Can you help me with some code if possible cause I'm not familiar with this

Answer (score 0):

This should solve your problem. First of all read students and grades in `teksti.txt` in an Map and then find max grade for each student.

```
public class NotaMax {
    private static Map<String, ArrayList<Integer>> students = new HashMap<>();

    private static void readTeksti() throws FileNotFoundException {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(new File("teksti.txt"));

        // read teksti.txt
        String[] line;
        while (input.hasNextLine()) {
            String rreshti = input.nextLine();
            line = rreshti.split(" ");
            ArrayList<Integer> grades = students.get(line[0]);

            if (grades == null) {
                grades = new ArrayList<>();
                grades.add(Integer.parseInt(line[1]));
                students.put(line[0], grades);
            } else {
                grades.add(Integer.parseInt(line[1]));
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) throws FileNotFoundException {

        readTeksti();

        max();

    }

    private static void max() throws FileNotFoundException {

        PrintStream output = new PrintStream(new File("max.txt"));
        List<Map.Entry<String,Integer>> maximums = new LinkedList<>();

        for (String current : students.keySet()) {
            ArrayList<Integer> grades = students.get(current);
            Integer max = Collections.max(grades);

            maximums.add(new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(current, max));
        }

        Collections.reverse(maximums);

        for (Map.Entry<String,Integer> current : maximums) {
            output.println("" + current.getKey() + ":" + current.getValue());
        }
    }
}
```

I assumed that `teksti.txt` is like :

```
saman 100
samad 80
samsam 70
samsam 90
saman 90
```